# Как правильно сериализовать XML с помощью JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Возник вопрос как правильно распарсить нижеприведенную часть XML файла c помощью JAXB:

```
      <question>
    <category>filled</category>
    <qtype>Описание типа вопроса</qtype>
    <weight>0</weight>
    <questionbody><![CDATA[Тело вопроса]]></questionbody>
    <answers>
      <answer type="true">
        <name><![CDATA[1 вариант ответа]]></name>
      </answer>
      <answer type="true">
        <name><![CDATA[2 вариант ответа]]></name>
      </answer>
    </answers>
  </question> 
  <question>
    <category>single</category>
    <qtype>Описание типа вопроса</qtype>
    <weight>0</weight>
    <questionbody><![CDATA[Тело вопроса]]></questionbody>
    <answers>
      <answer id="1" type="false">
        <name><![CDATA[Не верный]]></name>
      </answer>
      <answer id="2" type="true">
        <name><![CDATA[верный]]></name>
      </answer>
      <answer id="3" type="false">
        <name><![CDATA[не верный]]></name>
      </answer>
    </answers>
  </question>      
  <question>
    <category>multiply</category>
    <qtype>Описание типа вопроса</qtype>
    <weight>0</weight>
    <questionbody><![CDATA[Тело вопроса]]></questionbody>
    <answers>
      <answer id="1" type="true">
        <name><![CDATA[Верный]]></name>
      </answer>
      <answer id="2" type="true">
        <name><![CDATA[Верный]]></name>
      </answer>
      <answer id="3" type="false">
        <name><![CDATA[Не верный]]></name>
      </answer>
    </answers>
  </question>
  <question>
    <category>comparison</category>
    <qtype>Описание типа вопроса</qtype>
    <weight>10</weight>
    <questionbody><![CDATA[Тело вопроса]]></questionbody>
    <answers>
      <answer>
        <answbody id="1141"><![CDATA[1]]></answbody>
        <name id="1141"><![CDATA[1]]></name>
      </answer>
      <answer>
        <answbody id="2141"><![CDATA[2]]></answbody>
        <name id="2141"><![CDATA[2]]></name>
      </answer>
    </answers>
  </question>
  <question>
    <category>sort</category>
    <qtype>Описание типа вопроса</qtype>
    <weight>10</weight>
    <questionbody><![CDATA[Тело вопроса]]></questionbody>
    <answers>
      <answer type="true" order="1">
        <name><![CDATA[1]]></name>
      </answer>
      <answer type="true" order="2">
        <name><![CDATA[2]]></name>
      </answer>
    </answers>
  </question>
```

Вот что у меня получилось:

```
public class QuestionWrapper {
@XmlElement(name = "category")
private String category;

@XmlElement(name = "qtype")
private String qtype;

@XmlElement(name = "weight")
private int weight;

@XmlElement(name = "questionbody")
private String questionbody;

@XmlElement(name = "answer")
@XmlElementWrapper(name = "answers")
List<AnswerWrapper> answer;

public String getCategory() {
    return category;
}

public String getQtype() {
    return qtype;
}

public int getWeight() {
    return weight;
}

public String getQuestionbody() {
    return questionbody;
}

public List<AnswerWrapper> getAnswer() {
    return answer;
}
}
```

**Вопрос:** а вот как мне правильно разобрать answer, я так и не понял.

Он получается с разной структурой.

Менять структуру xml уже нельзя.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поробуйте так:

Класс Name:

```
public class Name {

    private String id;
    private String value;

    @XmlValue
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Класс Answbody:

```
public class Answbody {

    private String id;
    private String value;

    @XmlValue
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

Класс Answer:

```
public class Answer {

    private String type;
    private String order;
    private Name name;
    private Answbody answbody;



    @XmlElement
    public Answbody getAnswbody() {
        return answbody;
    }

    public void setAnswbody(Answbody answbody) {
        this.answbody = answbody;
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public String getOrder() {
        return order;
    }

    public void setOrder(String order) {
        this.order = order;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public Name getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(Name name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

**UPD:** как вы поняли, содержимое типа

```
<name><![CDATA[2 вариант ответа]]></name>
```

Будет находится в классе `Name` в поле `value`

Comment: Спасибо, все ясно и понятно. Оказалось все проще чем я ожидал)

Comment: Не за что! Обращайтесь